# SSRS 2017 Subscription Won't Open

Tags: reporting-services, subscription

I'm running SSRS on an OS 2016 standard and SQL Server 2017 and PowerBI. We're having problems, but I'll address one issue at a time.

I cannot open subscription services. I've successfully done this without problems in SQL Server 2012, but not the new box. I'm an administrator on the box and have every capability available for security - my role on the SSRS site is Admin. The error reads:

> An error has occurred.  Something went wrong.  Please try again later

Here's the log file - but I can't find a 200 reference anywhere?

> RSPortal!reportserverwebapp!RSPortal.exe!c!05/14/2018-10:57:27:: i
>   INFO: Sending response. Response code MAHEC\Janetb 500, Elapsed time
>   0:00:00.0107581 | RequestID = s_10ee693e-a340-45d7-a021-6a30961fef3c 
>   RSPortal!reportserverwebapp!RSPortal.exe!3!05/14/2018-10:57:27:: i
>   INFO: Received request GET /api/v2.0/me | RequestID =
>   s_77bbe02a-f5f4-4767-b1a3-7da5c58dba72 
>   RSPortal!reportserverwebapp!RSPortal.exe!d!05/14/2018-10:57:27:: i
>   INFO: Received request GET /api/v2.0/schedules | RequestID =
>   s_8a7661ed-20ff-4585-8313-1c5df05dd236 
>   RSPortal!reportserverwebapp!RSPortal.exe!c!05/14/2018-10:57:27:: i
>   INFO: Sending response. Response code MAHEC\Janetb 200, Elapsed time
>   0:00:00.0093358 | RequestID = s_8a7661ed-20ff-4585-8313-1c5df05dd236 
>   RSPortal!reportserverwebapp!RSPortal.exe!c!05/14/2018-10:57:27:: i
>   INFO: Sending response. Response code MAHEC\Janetb 200, Elapsed time
>   0:00:00.0448676 | RequestID = s_77bbe02a-f5f4-4767-b1a3-7da5c58dba72 
>   RSPortal!reportserverwebapp!RSPortal.exe!3!05/14/2018-10:57:27:: i
>   INFO: Received request POST /api/v2.0/schedules/model.describe |
>   RequestID = s_01998a7b-43fb-4825-8ba6-e90a911b39b7 
>   RSPortal!reportserverwebapp!RSPortal.exe!c!05/14/2018-10:57:28:: i
>   INFO: Sending response. Response code MAHEC\Janetb 200, Elapsed time
>   0:00:00.1642061 | RequestID = s_01998a7b-43fb-4825-8ba6-e90a911b39b7

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

After days and days of searching found this that worked:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6e831bc2-377e-47e6-a3bd-d601aa34438b/ssrs-subscription-settings-and-error-logs?forum=sqlreportingservices

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this message when trying to view subscriptions for an SSRS report.

For me, the issue was that somehow the subscription parameters became invalid. This may or may not have been because we did a SQL Server upgrade. After the upgrade I noticed that the requirements for creating a subscription are very stringent about how the date is typed in for date values.

The solution for me was to run a script like this on the report server DB.

```
update s set s.parameters = '<ParameterValues />'
FROM ReportServer.dbo.Subscriptions s
INNER JOIN ReportServer.dbo.Catalog c
ON s.Report_OID = c.ItemID
AND s.Description = 'Some name'
```

Answer (score 0):

my issue was a bit more silly, but I thought I would share anyways. My datasource was pointing to an outdated database. I'm not sure why the error couldnt have just told me the datasource was having problems, but either way, updating it fixed the issue for me.